# Generate an JSON array from a hash in JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

Given the following Ruby data structure:

```
data = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }
```

... I want to create the following JSON:

```
{"result":[
  {"letter":"a","number":"1"},
  {"letter":"b","number":"2"}
]}
```

How do I accomplish this using Rails' JBuilder?

Ideally, I'd like to go directly from the Hash to the JBuilder object, without translating the Hash to an Array first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy.

```
require 'jbuilder'

data = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }

out = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
    json.result data do |kv|
        json.letter kv[0]
        json.number kv[1]
    end
end

puts out  #=> {"result":[{"letter":"a","number":1},{"letter":"b","number":2}]}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid converting the hash key & value into a two-element array, but so far this is the only way I've found that works.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this notation since it isolates the key from the value:

```
require 'jbuilder'

data = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }

Jbuilder.encode do |json|
    json.result data do |k, v|
        json.letter k
        json.number v
    end
end
```

Basically identical to the previous answer but a little simpler